# Linux enscript -- footer doesn't work (final purpose is to add pager number at footer for PDF)

Tags: pdf, footer, enscript

Does anybody know how to add page number at footer for PDF? Followed is an example to show how to add page number at header by using `enscript, ps2pdf pdftk`. It works.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$1"
output="${1%.pdf}-header.pdf"
pagenum=$(pdftk "$input" dump_data | grep "NumberOfPages" | cut -d":" -f2)
enscript -L1 --header='|Page $% of $=|' --output - < <(for i in $(seq "$pagenum"); do echo; done) | ps2pdf - | pdftk "$input" multistamp - output $output
```

According to `enscript`'s manual, changing `--header` to `--footer` will work for footer. But in fact, no matter how I set the option for `--footer`, there is no footer at all. What's the matter? Does `--footer` work for `enscript`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone posted a good example of a working .hdr file on askubuntu along with alternative ways to invoke the new header file.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/544606/printing-footers-using-enscript

```
% -- code follows this line --
%Format: fmodstr    $D{%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y}
%Format: pagenumstr $V$%

%HeaderHeight: 38
%FooterHeight: 15

/do_header {   % print default simple header

% Footer
gsave
  d_footer_x d_footer_y HFpt_h 3 div add translate
  HF setfont

  user_footer_p {
    d_footer_x  d_footer_y moveto user_footer_left_str show

    d_footer_w user_footer_center_str stringwidth pop sub 2 div
    0 moveto user_footer_center_str show

    d_footer_x d_footer_w add user_footer_right_str stringwidth pop sub
    d_footer_y moveto user_footer_right_str show
  } if
grestore

% Header
gsave
  d_header_x d_header_y HFpt_h 3 div add translate
  HF setfont

  user_header_p {
    5 0 moveto user_header_left_str show

    d_header_w user_header_center_str stringwidth pop sub 2 div
    0 moveto user_header_center_str show

    d_header_w user_header_right_str stringwidth pop sub 5 sub
    0 moveto user_header_right_str show
  } {
    5 0 moveto fname show
    45 0 rmoveto fmodstr show
    45 0 rmoveto pagenumstr show
  } ifelse
grestore

} def
```

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work, I modified one of the existing header files (simple.hdr) and then passed the parameter --header-files=name-of-new file on the command line. then remove the --header option in teh command line.

Comment: What is your modification for simple.hdr? Does your modification work for `footer`?